# How can be changed the path to save folder in FIFA10 (PC)?

Tags: fifa-10

I am running out of space on C: drive and most of the space is taken from FIFA 10 save folder located in my documents? How can I change the path to the folder so I can move it to drive D:, because if I just moved it the game didn't find it and asks to create a new profile?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a symbolic link if you don't want to move all of your documents:

- Move the save folder to where you want it to be.
- Open a terminal window with admin privileges.
- Use the following command:

  > mklink /D "C:\Users\ACCOUNT\Documents\Path\To\Saves" "D:\Path\to\new\folder"

Once this is done the game should save its files to the new location without even knowing about its existence. Just make sure the target is valid (e.g. in case it would be a removable drive).

To revert the whole thing just remove the symbolic link (which will look like a shortcut) and move the folder back to its original position.

Comment: Please watch out with junctions - especially if you recommend them to users who don't know what they're doing.

Comment: Care to elaborate? Creating circular references/infinite recursions?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer I would like to try that solution. What do you mean with open terminal window I thought it was writting your command in cmd but it doesn't recognize it. I searched the web but the answers are server related could you please explain the steps for opening the terminal window? I am running windows HP

Comment: Just run "cmd" with admin rights, e.g. by typing it into the start menu/screen, right clicking and picking the option to run it as administrator. Be extra careful when typing the parameters. Wrong values will most likely crash the program. Also make sure you don't create some link that points to its parent directory or similar, since some programs might screw up once they encounter something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know wether one is able to change FIFA10s save directory,
but as I think this isn't your main problem, I may still help you :D

The folder Documents isn't a real folder. It's just a view on different folders.
Which means, you can easily alter/add a new location.
(FIFA will still store its files to "documents", but documents is on your other partition)

> Windows 7
>
> 1. Create a new folder that you want to assign as My Documents folder,
>      if you have another drive or partition ex: drive D: I recommended
>      that you create My Document Folder to that drive.
> 2. browse to "C:\Users\" using Windows Explorer (Press WINDOWS KEY + E
>      to access this). Then, right click on My Documents and select
>      Properties: Then Click Location Tab
> 3. Then click Move then browse to new location for your My Documents
>      folder. Once you find new folder for your document click Select
>      Folder.
> 4. then click Apply, there will be pop up message to confirm the
>      changed, click Yes to move your documents to the new location, or
>      click No to leave your documents in the original location.

Take a look at [this](http://www.gokhiel.com/2009/05/how-to-change-my-documents-folder.html) page for any other Windows-Version than Win7.